# Cannot make bootstrap columns "fluid"

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make my divs "fluid" in a sense.
Example:
I have three divs and each has a class : `<div col-12-xs col-6-md>`

This means that on a medium and large screen div one and two would be side by side and div 3 would be below them.

```
    <div class="container">   
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 box">One</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 box">
                Two
                <br>
                Two
                <br>
                Two
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 box">Three</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So if this example code is used you would obviously be pushing the third div down while div two grows in height as more content is added.

My question is this.
Is there a way that I can make diff three stay below div one as div two grows in height but when the screen is smaller div two should still move beneath div one and above dif three.

[Example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbXG1.png)
As you can see in the picture I would like to have div three below div one even if div two grows in height but on a small screen div two should move between div one and two.

Can this be done with bootstrap?

Comment: Can anyone suggest a better way of asking the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the second div to `float:right`. I have added `pull-right` class for that as you are using `bootstrap`

here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ze4g18a7/

```css
        div {
            text-align:center;
            font-size:20px;
        }

        .div1 {
            height: 200px;
            background-color: #ffe6ff;
        }

        .div2 {
            height: 400px;
            background-color: #ccfff5;
        }

        .div3 {
            height: 200px;
            background-color: #80dfff;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="div1 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">1</div>
        <div class="div2 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 pull-right">2</div>
        <div class="div3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">3</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This has to be the fix. I'm not getting it to work on my own code but that might be my bootstrap version or that i'm populating the second div with handlebars.

Comment: I see now that it does not work when when trying to use it with col classes.
But it does work when used within a div with a col class.
This is an issue on my side and must be plug-in.

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using 3.x or 4.x

Comment: if your are using `bootstrap 4.x`, make 1st and 3rd `div`s `float;left` and 2nd as `float:right` and make the parent `row` `display:block`

Comment: That was it... Just had to add the block class to the row.
I'f I could buy you a drink I would.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a clearfix after the first 2 divs, like so:

```
<div class="container">   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 box">One</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 box">
            Two
            <br>
            Two
            <br>
            Two
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix col-xs-12></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 box">Three</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will cause the third div to always stay below the top two